# Remove symbolic link to development version

Tags: python, pandas

On the [pandas developers page](http://pandas.pydata.org/developers.html#running-the-test-suite) it says describes how to work with your development version of pandas.

It mentions that `python setup.py develop` will allow you to always use your development environment:

> This makes a symbolic link that tells the Python interpreter to import
>   pandas from your development directory. Thus, you can always be using
>   the development version on your system without being inside the clone
>   directory.

It doesn't say where this symbolic link is created, nor does it mention how to "undo" this operation. I had a quick look in `setup.py` but couldn't find where the symbolic link is created.

So if I run `python setup.py develop` how can I get back to using my release version of pandas?

Comment: `pip uninstall pandas` followed by `pip install pandas`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the symlink created using `python setup.py develop` via:

```
python setup.py develop --uninstall
```

As for the symlink itself, it's not strictly a symlink but rather a normal file with an `.egg-link` extension. It will be created in the `site-packages` folder of the Python installation you used to run `python setup.py develop`. Using a virtualenv named my_test_virtualenv, mine was created at `/home/chuck/.virtualenvs/my_test_virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas.egg-link`. The file itself contains a single line - the path to your cloned pandas repo.